# Batch Rename Folders Randomly

Tags: batch-file, random, directory, rename

I need some help to create a batch file that renames all folders in a specific directory to random names/numbers like "!random!" do. I know how to do with files but not with folders. Any suggestions?

[Example of my idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Fir.png)

---

I have tried this way without any luck.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (
"%cd%\" ) do (
    ren "%%~a" "!RANDOM!"
)
```

Comment: assuming you use `ren` for files. It does also work for folders.

Comment: I'd advise you to read the documentation about `for` - **for /?** from the prompt.

Comment: You cant rename the current working folder.